# Queen first, lose (or draw) later 3

Tags: pawn-endgame

Base: [Queen first, lose (or draw) later](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40655/queen-first-lose-or-draw-later)

3. What is the most economical pawn endgame position where Black queens first but White draws, White pawns no higher than 4th rank on time of Black queening?

Comment: I doubt there's a position like that without involving some stalemate tactic

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: Saving two pawns for an optimal solution

Black queens first but cannot win, no white pawn higher than the 4th rank, 1+1 pawns :

```
[FEN "8/8/8/6k1/8/7K/6pP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

1...g1Q is stalemate and any other move draws as well

Funnily it is also possible with 0+2 pawns:

```
[FEN "8/8/8/6k1/8/6pK/6p1/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

1...g1Q/R stalemate

1...g1N/B 2.Kxg3=

1...Kf4 2.Kxg2=

---

*Previous answer*

An attempt with 2 pawns each:

```
[FEN "k7/8/8/7p/7P/7K/6pP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

1...g1Q is an immediate stalemate. Other Black moves wouldn't win either:

1...Kb7 2.Kxg2=

1...g1R stalemate

1...g1B 2.Kg3 and the Ph5 will be captured

1...g1N 2.Kg2 Ne2 3.Kf3 Nd4 4.Kf4 and White is better !

Comment: Ah, yes. David was right. Now that you posted it, I remember it as a well know study motif...and how to shave off another pawn :-) Feel free to find it yourself and edit the answer (which incidentally saves me from posting the other 4 similar draw questions, THX!)