# Queen first, lose (or draw) later 4

Tags: pawn-endgame

Base: [Queen first, lose (or draw) later](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40655/queen-first-lose-or-draw-later)

4. What is the most economical pawn endgame position where Black queens first but White wins, White pawns no higher than 6th rank on time of Black queening? (3+1 pawns suffice, so try to find or even beat that!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously optimal :

```
[FEN "8/5p2/8/8/8/1P6/2K5/k7 b - - 0 1"]
```

Black promotes first, with the wP still on the 6th rank, but they got mated after

> 1...c1Q 2.g7 Kh7 3.g8Q Kh6 4.Qg6#